# Как при плавном скролле в jquery сделать запас места, так как хедер занимает некоторе пространство и наезжает на загловок блока к которому скроллимся

Tags: jquery

```
  $('.menu a, .footer__logo, .footer__list a').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('href'),
      top = $(id).offset().top;
    $('body,html').animate(
      {
        scrollTop: top,
      },
      1200,
    );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно скролить к месту чуть выше блока на размер хедера:

```js
$('.menu a, .footer__logo, .footer__list a').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('href'),
        top = $(id).offset().top - $('.header').outerHeight();
    $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: top }, 1200 );
});
```

Comment: Гениально, это то - что мне и нужно было, спасибо большое! Поднял ответ